# Centering subviews in UIView does't work in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView(called **innerView**) inside a UIView(**outerView**). The outerView has Autolayout constraints and is always centered in the root view. The innerView is just placed in the outerView arbitrarily without any constraints. And they are all linked to the view controller by outlets.

I want the innerView to be always centered inside the outerView. Of course, i can use autolayout, but i just have to test if i can move it by code(because i found it is a problem in my real project)

unfortunately, i find i can't move the innerView with code. Anyone knows the reason?

here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // outerView is 300 X 300
    @IBOutlet weak var outerView: UIView!

    // innerView is 140 X 140, and it is the subview of outerView
    @IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView!

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        innerView.center = CGPoint(x: outerView.bounds.midX, y: outerView.bounds.midY)
        innerView.autoresizingMask = .None
        // result is : (150.0, 150.0) which is correct
        print(innerView.center)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // result is : (78.0, 222.0) which is not correct
        print(innerView.center)
    }
}
```

Comment: If your print `outerView.bounds` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, what will you get?

Comment: i get `(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 300.0)`. if i print `innerView.center` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` after the setting, i get `(150, 150)` which is correct, but if i print it in `viewDidAppear`, i get `(78.0, 222.0)`  which is obvious not i want.

Comment: You can add autolayout constraints programmatically as well.

Comment: Did you set autoresizing mask to zero? This seems that the center is set correctly but layout moves it when resizing the controller to screen size.

Comment: yeah, you are right. But the innerView's frame may be changed in my real project, but i found it didn't work in my project, so i test here.

Comment: @Sulthan, i think that's the problem as well. But no autolayout constrains of the innerView are set, so i am very confused.

Comment: @WJRain I am not talking about *autolayout* but *autoresizing*.

Comment: @Sulthan, sorry, a little confused about the difference of  autolayout constrains and autoresizing mask. But i am clear now. There is one of which raw value is 36. So I set it to .None, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it is just an event to inform you, that all subviews of viewcontroller's root view are positioned at the desired places. You are not guaranteed that all the rest subviews of those subviews will also be aligned, since it is a responsibility of the parent view itself.

So move your center innerView code into:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        innerView.center = CGPoint(x:outerView.bounds.midX , y:outerView.bounds.midY)
}
```

If support orientation:

```
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
innerView.center = CGPoint(x:outerView.bounds.midX , y:outerView.bounds.midY)
    }
```

Comment: yeah, i have tried that, it works. But it is not perfect, it only works in portrait  mode, not in landscape mode. The reason is obvious. Trait changing does't make `viewDidAppear` called once again.

Comment: Finally, it works. Really appreciated. But i still have two questions. 1) usually, we change view geometry in `viewWillLayoutSubview`. As you mentioned, it is only the place to change the layout of the subviews of the view controller' root view, then where should we change the view geometry of subviews of subviews? 2) `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated already, so it is not proper to be used.

Comment: I didn't mention ```viewWillLayoutSubview```, Normally do what you can by constraint. ```viewWillTransitionToSize``` replace ```willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation```. If this answer helps please accept it, thanks

Comment: Replace `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` with `viewWillTransitionToSize` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
innerView.center = outerView.convertPoint(outerView.center, fromView: outerView.superview)
```

Comment: Tried, still doesn't work. But really thanks. In fact, I think they are the same things, just going two different way.